# Django model foreign key, filtering?

Tags: django, database, django-models

Let's say I have models like that:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
  name = [...]
  is_attendable = models.BooleanField([...])

class AttendanceList(models.Model):
 what_to_attend = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 who_attends_it = [...]
```

So if I set is_attendable to False, it shouldn't be listed on the attendance list. It's like filtering the foreign key's query... How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class AttendanceList(models.Model):
    what_to_attend = models.ForeignKey(
        Assignment,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'is_attendable': True}
    )
```

This will automatically apply filtering for the `ModelForm`s, and the forms in a `ModelAdmin` as well as in serializers.

This will however only filter when *creating* or *updating* an `AttendanceList`: if later the `Assignment` sets `is_attendable` to `False`, then the `AttendanceList`s that are already referring to that `Assignment` will *not* be updated, removed or prevent updating.

Comment: Does this work when you would rather want to get a "greaten than" condition? so instead of is_attendable:true, you want ppl_attended_it__lt: 15 for example

Comment: @Szottyadtkifli: yes, you can use `{'ppl_attended_it__lt': 15}`, or any other condition like you are passing it in a `.filter(...)` clause.